# Product different prices and options per customer group

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, customer-group, custom-options

I am looking to set up 3 simple products

1. 1 box - 700g
2. 8 boxes - 700g
3. 12 boxes - 700g

I would then make a configurable product based on a new custom attribute of "Number of boxes" and associate these products thus allowing customers to choose which option they wish to purchase.

The question is though based on the customer group I want to do the following

- Have a different price if you are logged in as a trade instead of retail
- Hide 1 box 700g product option if logged in as trade

Please, could someone tell me how this is possible?

1 way I thought would be possible is that I could have different configurable products

1. Retail configurable product
2. Trade configurable product

And then only associate the relevant options. I would then use something like http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-groups-catalog2.html to hide the trade product from the retail customer group.

I am not sure if this is the best method though?

Cheers